# Abap Pretty Print in Html Plugin

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, intellisense, abap

I need a plugin which pretty print my code in html like sap gui same button.

I have a kendo editor and when I copy some codes from gui and paste to editor, It takes intellisense of code like this;

[image: It works fine]

It is works fine but when I need to change this code and after my work done I want to pretty print this code.

Is there any plugin to make to this job or must I write my own plugin ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ has this feature. Copy the code and select the abap syntax.

Comment: I know this feature but can I use it for MVC Web Project? @hovmat

Comment: That's syntax highlighting, not pretty printing, which actually formats the spacing of the code and whatnot.